# A domain in which the Dirichlet Laplacian has eigenvalues of all orders

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

I am trying to come up with an example to the following.

Construct a domain $\Omega$ in all dimensions $n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that the spectrum of the Dirichlet Laplacian on such a domain (i.e., the Laplacian with Dirichlet boundary conditions on the boundary of $\Omega$) has the following properties:

For any given $m \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$, each eigenvalue of the Dirichlet Laplacian on $\Omega$ has multiplicity $m$

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly. Can anybody help?

Thanks

Comment: At a first look I'm thinking of $m$ disjoint intervals. I could be wrong...

Comment: The question needs rewriting. Did you reproduce the order of words correctly?  A domain cannot be "in all dimensions $n$". It can have dimension $n$ for one value of $n$ only.  Also, is a domain assumed connected? If so, then in one dimension all eigenvalues are simple: they are $4\pi^2n^2/l^2$, where $l$ is the length of interval. Finally, why does "for any given $m$" come after "construct a domain"? It would make sense to ask, for any given $m$, to construct a domain such that eigenvalues have multiplicity  $m$.  Not "construct a domain such that for any given $m$..."

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have added a bit of a premise as to how the question came up. It has to do with Thm. 2 and the remark that follows it. (p.356 Evans, PDE 2nd edition). Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, the domain does not have to be connected.

Comment: Then, take any bounded domain together with infinitely many (non-intersecting) copies.

Comment: Thanks. But can you please clarify 'infinitely many non intersecting copies'?. Do you mean copies of the bounded domain itself? (then they of course intersect??).

Comment: The copies that gerw refers to don't have to intersect: you can place them apart (moving a domain around does not change anything about eigenvalues). You can have infinitely many disjoint copies of unit ball, for example.